# TypeFamilyDependencies: why is this injectivity annotation accepted?

Tags: haskell, type-families

Consider this code (requires singletons-2.2):

```
    {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeOperators, KindSignatures, TypeInType, TypeFamilyDependencies, UndecidableInstances #-}

module Bug where

import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.Singletons.Prelude (Map, SndSym0)
import GHC.TypeLits (Nat)

data Payload = A | B

newtype NewType a = NewType Int

type List = [Payload]
type NatList = [(Nat, Payload)]

type StripNatList (natList :: NatList) = Map SndSym0 natList

type family Family (natList :: NatList) = (r :: Type) | r -> natList where
    Family '[] = ()
    Family xs  = NewType (StripNatList xs)
```

I don't understand why GHC is okay with injectivity annotation for `Family`: `r -> natList`.

These two types:

```
type Foo = Family '[ '(0, 'A), '(1, 'B)]
type Bar = Family '[ '(0, 'A), '(0, 'B)]
```

are obviously map to the same type:

```
*Bug Data.Singletons.Prelude> :kind! Foo
Foo :: *
= NewType ('A :$$$ '['B])
*Bug Data.Singletons.Prelude> :kind! Bar
Bar :: *
= NewType ('A :$$$ '['B])
```

Why this is not rejected?

Comment: This looks as a bug to me. If others agree on this, you should [report it](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReportABug).

Comment: Changing `StripNatList` to a type family or inlining the definition inside `Family` causes the error to be correctly triggered. Even more strangely, e.g. `type family X (x :: NatList) = (r :: List) | r -> x where X x = StripNatList x` (i.e. same thing but removing `NewType`) correctly gives an error *regardless* of how you define `StripNatList`. The behaviour in this edge case is so wild it is almost certainly a bug...

Comment: @chi Thanks. I made a ticket https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12430#ticket